# FluentValidation when does not raises any message

Tags: c#, fluent, fluentvalidation

I have a problem with this code:

```
RuleFor(field => field.TermEndDate)
    .NotEmpty()
    .When(x => x.TermEndDate == x.TermStartDate)
    .WithMessage("error...");
```

I set `TermEndDate = DateTime.Now` but no message raises!

My test code is:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var command = new AddTermCommand
{
    SchoolId = Guid.NewGuid(),
    TermStartDate = now,
    TermEndDate = now
};
var cmd = command.Validate();
if (!cmd.IsValid)
    Console.WriteLine(cmd.Errors.First().ErrorMessage);
```

Comment: `DateTime.Now` before  `!=` `DateTime.Now` now.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you express the validation rule that you wish to have in natural language? The reason I am asking is that the `When` method is used to limit when the validator should run. It doesn't specify a validation rule.

Comment: I'm trying to use `When()` but it doesn't work !?

Comment: What is your expectation that `When` does?

Comment: when I put 'When(1 == 2)' or 'When(1 != 2)' but nothing raises!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

As I noted in the comments, the first problem is that you cannot really compare with `DateTime.Now` since calling `DateTime.Now` after some time (even very small) gives you a different value.

The second problem is that you are using the `When` method. The `When` method is used to specify a condition to run the validation in the first place (for example, you can specify that you want to validate this property only if the value of some other property is 1), it cannot be used to specify a validation rule. Instead you can use the `Must` method like this:

```
RuleFor(field => field.TermEndDate)
    .NotEmpty()
    .Must(x => (DateTime.Now - x).Duration() > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
    .WithMessage("error...");
```

Here I am using `Must` to say that the value of `TermEndDate` should be at least 1 minute more or less (1 minute away from `DateTime.Now`) than the time when I run the validation (which is when I invoke `Validate`).

**UPDATE:**

To compare `TermEndDate` with `TermStartDate`, you can do it like this:

```
RuleFor(field => field.TermEndDate)
    .Must((cmd, enddate) => enddate != cmd.TermStartDate)
    .WithMessage("error...");
```

Comment: Thank you, 'Must' raises message error.. but i cant compare 'TermEndDate ' vs 'TermStartDate'!

Answer (score 2):

Your rule will never fire because `TermEndDate` will **never** be equal to `DateTime.Now`; you're comparing a value from the past with a moving value of `Now`.

Either try verifying against a specific date or just against the day:

```
RuleFor(field => field.TermEndDate)
.NotEmpty()
.When(x => x.TermEndDate.Date == DateTime.Today)
.WithMessage("error...");
```